# Is there any way to set a break point for debug in the environment in which gems like binding.pry are not installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From this April, I participated in a new project in which gems for debug are not installed and I am not allowed to install new ones.

I would like to set a break point and see the inside of variables like binding.pry.
I googled to debug in such a way without newly installing gems or by using extensions of VScode, but most of the pages require me to install ones.

It would be highly appreciated if you would share with me your ideas to debug in the way.

== Additional Information on April 8th, 2020 ==

Ruby version is 1.8.7.
Rails version is 2.3.5.

Comment: No, Ruby does not have a built in debugger that lets you set breakpoints. But you can use pry without adding it to the Gemfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ruby doesn't really have a built-in breakpoint-based debugger in that sense.

The closest thing you can do is start an IRB session mid-program, which halts it and allows you to inspect the current state of the program by evaluating Ruby commands. This is available in Ruby 2.4 and above as `binding.irb`. (There are docs available for this on the [Binding class](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Binding.html).)

IRB doesn't let you step forwards like Pry with Pry-Nav does, but you can just insert `binding.irb` expressions in as many places as you need, and `exit` from IRB to "step" to the next one.

Take ths simple program. I want to check the value of those three variables I've assigned, so I put `binding.irb` there:

```
puts "=== Hello! ==="

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

binding.irb

puts "=== Goodbye! ==="
```

Upon running this program, Ruby will give you an IRB prompt after it's evaluated `c = 3`, where you can run Ruby code to check values and whatnot (type `exit` to leave):

```
=== Hello! ===
From: test.rb @ line 7 :
    2: 
    3: a = 1
    4: b = 2
    5: c = 3
    6: 
 => 7: binding.irb
    8: 
    9: puts "=== Goodbye! ==="
irb(main):001:0> a
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> b
=> 2
irb(main):003:0> c
=> 3
irb(main):004:0> exit
=== Goodbye! ===
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your idea. Unfortunately, ruby version is 1.8.7, so I cannot try what you suggested. However, I did not know I could do that and I will try it in other projects.